# Avoiding debugger warning in IsNothing() statement

Tags: c#, vb.net, try-catch, compiler-warnings

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and have the following code block. The code checks the file type of a specific file (that's why there are return True/False in it). If it encounters an error it also returns false. The warnings I get are that I use the fs/br variables before they are initialized, which is true. That's why I have the IsNothing statements, but I get the warning IN the IsNothing statements and I have no idea how to avoid that because I don't want to put the `fs = New FileStream(fn, FileMode.Open)` and `br = ...` statements outside the Try/Catch block.

The code itself works so the warning is not really a problem, but it still bothers me to have them. Does anyone see a solution how this block can be changed to offer the same safety without warnings?

Both VB.NET or C# answers are welcome.

```vb
            Dim fs As FileStream
            Dim br As BinaryReader
            Try
                fs = New FileStream(fn, FileMode.Open) 'Open the file
                br = New BinaryReader(fs) 'Initilize the reader
                'File reading code omitted here
                br.Close() 'Close the reader and underlying stream
            Catch
                If Not IsNothing(fs) Then fs.Close() 'Warning here
                If Not IsNothing(br) Then br.Close() 'and here
                Return False
            End Try
```

Comment: Not the debugger, it is the compiler that issues the warning.  It is not quite smart enough to understand that the IsNothing() method was actually written to deal with an uninitialized object.  Don't write code like this, use the *Using* statement instead.

Comment: Thank you Hans, I explained my (wrong) motifs for not using Using statements in the comments to the accepted answers but I will change my code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That's why I have the IsNothing statements

That suggests you expect the values to be IsNothing before they're given a specific value. In C#, this wouldn't just be a warning - it would be an error.

I have two suggestions:

- If you *really* want to follow this pattern, just set the values to `Nothing` to start with:

  ```
  Dim fs As FileStream = Nothing
  Dim br As BinaryReader = Nothing
  ```
- If at all possible, reorganize your code so you can just use `Using` statements instead, which will close the streams at the end of the block either way. We can't tell enough about the rest of the code to help you do that at the moment though.

Comment: I have the IsNothing part because it might already throw an exception at `fs = New FileStream(fn, FileMode.Open)`. That's why I didn't want to use using statements. Actually a quick question about that: If I would do it like Try -> Using fs as New Filestream(...) --> Code --> End Using --> Catch --> Return False --> End Try  and an exception would occure: Would the stream be closed in this case or would it stay open?

Comment: @Jens: I don't see how what you've said is a reason to not use a `Using` statement. I would probably have two nested `Using` statements - one for the `FileStream`, and one for the `BinaryReader` - although you could probably get away with just `Using reader as BinaryReader = new BinaryReader(new Filestream(...))` if we can assume that the `BinaryReader` constructor isn't going to throw an exception.

Comment: My mistake was to assume that if an exception occured in the using statement that the stream would not be closed (file would stay opened). But this is not the case so I will go with the nested using statements inside of a try/catch. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-write this without having to use a nested Using block -you can do it all in one line - I don't believe you can do this in C#:

```
    Try
        Using fs As New FileStream(fn, FileMode.Open), br As New BinaryReader(fs)
            Try

            Catch ex As Exception
                'an exception here indicates an issue reading the file
            End Try
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        'an exception here indicates an issue opening the filestream or reader
    End Try
```

The using block ensures that the objects are disposed of without the need to explicitly call `.Dispose` it also calls `.Close` so you don't even need that line

Comment: Thank you. This is basically what I had changed it to after the previous answers. I left out the inner Try/Catch because I don't need the distiction. I have also found in preliminary testing that the stream is closed even if an exception is thrown in the inner part. Good answer.